# "localizedStandardCompare" depends on the language preference of the iOS device

Tags: ios

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor,nil]];
```

I am working on an app that has a list of names, where all names are in Íslenska(Icelandic) language.
The above code works fine if the language selected for apps in settings is Íslenska(Icelandic) but the sort descriptor fails if the language is other than Íslenska(Icelandic).

Is there any way to resolve this dependency problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "sort descriptor fails"?

Comment: Toress should come before Tóress,but this is not the case when sort descriptor fails ,it shows Tóress before Toress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should create a `sortDescriptor` that will compare strings using `is_IS` locale.

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptior =[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES comparator:^(NSString* str1, NSString* str2) {   

static NSStringCompareOptions comparisonOptions =
    NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSNumericSearch |
    NSWidthInsensitiveSearch | NSForcedOrderingSearch;

    return [str1 compare:str2 options:comparisonOptions range:NSMakeRange(0, str1.length) locale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"is_IS"]];
}];
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unsupported NSSortDescriptor (comparator blocks are not supported)'

Comment: Oh I see now - you're trying to use this sort descriptor with CoreData fetch, and that is not supported... What you can do is to fetch regularly (without sorting), and sort the result array with the above sort descriptor.